# Is there a difference between these two generic signatures of a "max" function for a collection

Tags: java, generics

Is there a practical difference between these two signatures:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T max(Collection<T> c)
```

and

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(Collection<? extends T> c)
```

I cannot think of a single use case where these two would not be interchangeable.

Then what is the reason for having both ? super T and ? extends T in the standard max() method in the Java Collections:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T max(Collection<? extends T> coll)
```

Edit:
This question is not about the difference between `<? super T>` and `<? extends T>`. The get/put principle is quite clear to me.
The question is about the difference between these 2 particular signatures and why did the creators of the Java Collections API decided to create a mix out of these two signatures for their standard "max" function.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java)

Comment: A more interesting question is is there any difference between the `Collection<? extends T> coll` in the parameters of the standard max() method and if it were declared `Collection<T> coll`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example when the two are not interchangeable is:

```
static class A implements Comparable<Object> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(final Object o) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

a list with instances of `A` works with the first `max()` and fails for the second `max()`:

```
error: method max2 in class Generics cannot be applied to given types;
    max2(Arrays.asList(new A()));
    ^
required: Collection<? extends T>
found: List<A>
reason: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
  equality constraints: Object
  upper bounds: Comparable<T>
where T is a type-variable:
  T extends Comparable<T> declared in method <T>max2(Collection<? extends T>)
```

another example:

```
static class A {}
static class B extends A implements Comparable<A>{
    @Override
    public int compareTo(final A o) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

`max()` has been designed this way to make sure its signature is not changed and all the compiled code depending on `max()` (pre-Java 5 code) returning an `Object` can still work, more details in [Converting Legacy Code to Use Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/convert.html).

Comment: Yep, correct. Seems these two signatures are not as interchangeable as I thought. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Taking a simple example

Animal:

```
class Animal extends Mammal
```

Cat:

```
class Cat extends Animal
```

Lets break down the signature.

```
max(Collection<? extends T> coll)
```

This is because the max should be accepting a list of Animal as well as Cat.
Now, the remaining part:

```
<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

This covers the case where I have my Animal class signature something like this:

```
Animal extends Mammal implements Comparable<Mammal>
```

So, my comparable object can accept any of it's parents and still do a logical comparison. I know this isn't a very practical example, but I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

> Then what is the reason for having both ? super T and ? extends T in the standard max() method in the Java Collections:

Is just to offer a max operation that is as versatile as possible given that the operations that it is going to perform on that collection and their elements are just `iterator().next` and `compareTo`. In other words it declares the weakest constrains needed on its argument type that still allows its code to compile.

Comment: The public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(Collection<? extends T> c)  variant of the signature offers exactly that. 
So in a way I can see why this second variant can be considered slightly better than the first. But I still don't see a valid reason for the mix.

Comment: Currently im on my mobile device so is difficult to look at it with detail right now ... but a brainless test is to pull the code of those methods and play with the signatures and see why those changes would result in compilation problems.